# Can I insert images from file in Photoshop actions

Tags: adobe-photoshop, automation, actions

I want to include inserting images into Photoshop action files. Is this possible or do they have to include a stop to do this manually?

Answer (score 1):

This can easily be accomplished using the "File" > "Place embedded" (or "File" > "Place Linked") commands. No need to stop.

Comment: It does have to be the same image each time though. And if you move or delete the image, the action will break. Also note that this creates a smart object.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is kinda asking two different things, but if I deciphered it right, what you want can be done.

You can add user interaction to a specific action by checking the "dialog checkbox" I don't know if it has a proper name.

1. Expand the action in the `Actions` panel
2. Find the recorded `Place` action and click the empty box on the left.
   [image]

With this the action will stop at the Place dialog and then continue when the dialog is closed, as long as you don't cancel.

Answer (score 0):

I just had one new idea and sort of works. Start the script by loading the image which need to be placed and load them into a stack using the script for that. Save this image to you location and uncheck all layers but 1. Then place this image in you file and by using shortcuts edit the placed image and uncheck and check a lower layer in the file. For me this worked.

Though when each different image needs to have a different location, that a tough one.